# SQL SERVER 2008 GET LAST INSERTED VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

This is my table.

```
Ticket(id int auto_increment,name varchar(50));
```

after inserting into this table i want send id and name to mail..
how can i get the last Inserted value.

help to solve this...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look into: [Scope_identity](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

```
SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

The table which is having Identity Property from that table we can get the last inserted record id will be like this

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

**OR**

But this is not a safe technique:

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Ticket
```

**OR**

This is also not a safe technique:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Ticket ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Comment: Your second and third suggestions are not safe under conditions of concurrency.

Comment: This will work but there will be a problem when simultaneously more than one entry is inserted in the table. e.g., At the time you fetch the record, another record is inserted in-between then you wont get the correct result so this is under condition of concurrency...Hope now you are clear..:)...@DavidA

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get last primary key inserted value on your table. I guess it should be the `ID` value. Once you have it, do a `SELECT` using this ID and there you have it.

There is also `@@IDENTITY` but there are some differences using one or the another that could lead to inaccuracies on the values.

Check these detailed articles for more insights, a detailed description on how to use them, why they are different and some demo code:

- [**For the last time, NO, you can't trust IDENT_CURRENT()**](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current)
- [**sql server identity vs scope_identity vs ident_current retrieve last inserted identity of record**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server before 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 ([Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779)):

> You may receive incorrect values when using SCOPE_IDENTITY() and
>   @@IDENTITY

In that case, the OUTPUT clause is the safest mechanism:

```
DECLARE @InsertedRows AS TABLE (Id int)
DECLARE @NewId AS INT
INSERT INTO HumanResources.Employees
  ( /* column names */)
OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @InsertedRows
  VALUES (/* column values */)
SELECT @NewId = Id FROM @InsertedRows
```

Comment: Is this needed within a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

add auto increement Field in your table like.... index (INT,AUTO INCREEMENT)
then before insert or any operation done c get your last record by getting max(index)

Comment: Please fix the syntax to let people understand and try what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

> this might also helpful in some scenarios

```
SELECT Top 1 CAST(Id AS int) as ID from table ORDER BY [Id] DESC;
```